# Why does this buffer point to unaddressable bytes?

Tags: c, sizeof, fread

EDIT: Thanks to repliers I have changed fread to (...sizeof buffer, 1,...), but now I get this error in valgrind:

```
==2409== Invalid read of size 4
==2409==    at 0x51AB8D0: fread (iofread.c:41)
==2409==    by 0x4007B6: main (recover2.c:31)
==2409==  Address 0x5502000 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==2409== 
==2409== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==2409==    at 0x51B8787: _IO_sgetn (genops.c:495)
==2409==    by 0x51AB93E: fread (iofread.c:42)
==2409==    by 0x4007B6: main (recover2.c:31)
==2409== 
==2409== Invalid read of size 8
==2409==    at 0x51B8787: _IO_sgetn (genops.c:495)
==2409==    by 0x51AB93E: fread (iofread.c:42)
==2409==    by 0x4007B6: main (recover2.c:31)
==2409==  Address 0x40 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==2409== 
==2409== 
==2409== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==2409==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x40
==2409==    at 0x51B8787: _IO_sgetn (genops.c:495)
==2409==    by 0x51AB93E: fread (iofread.c:42)
==2409==    by 0x4007B6: main (recover2.c:31)
==2409==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==2409==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==2409==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==2409==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==2409==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

---

I'm new here so I hope this makes sense. I'm writing this code to retrieve data from a file and copy it out to jpeg files. The code is meant to find a jpg file by its header then write it to files. The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

FILE* file = fopen("card.raw", "r");
if (file == NULL)
{ 
    printf("Could not open file!\n");
    return 1;
}

char title[7];
int currentImage = 0;
uint8_t buffer[512];
FILE* img;
while (fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 512, file) == 1)
{
printf("found data!\n");
if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff)
{
    if (buffer[3] == 0xe0 || buffer[3] == 0xe1 || buffer[3] == 0xe2 || buffer[3] == 0xe3 || buffer[3] == 0xe4 || buffer[3] == 0xe5 || buffer[3] == 0xe6 || buffer[3] == 0xe7 || buffer[3] == 0xe8 || buffer[3] == 0xe9 || buffer[3] == 0xea || buffer[3] == 0xeb || buffer[3] == 0xec || buffer[3] == 0xed || buffer[3] == 0xee || buffer[3] == 0xef)
    {
        printf("Found new jpg!\n");
        sprintf(title, "%03d.jpg", currentImage);
        img = fopen(title, "a");
        currentImage++;
        printf("size of buffer to print is %lu\n", sizeof(buffer));
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, img);
        }
}
else if (currentImage > 0)
{ 
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, img);


}

}
}
```

I am getting a segmentation fault once it finds a jpeg, and does the fwrite, and then returns to the while loop.

The valgrind error is:

```
==1866== Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==1866==    at 0x5228810: __read_nocancel (syscall-template.S:81)
==1866==    by 0x51B63B8: _IO_file_xsgetn (fileops.c:1438)
==1866==    by 0x51AB93E: fread (iofread.c:42)
==1866==    by 0x4007C3: main (recover2.c:31)
==1866==  Address 0xfff001000 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==1866== 
==1866== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==1866==    at 0x0: ???
==1866==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==1866== 
==1866== 
==1866== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==1866==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x0
==1866==    at 0x0: ???
```

I'm new to this so still learning about memory and etc, so any help in understanding why it's gone wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Be warned not to substantially change your question after you got answers. Anyway, you are printing 8 characters into `title`, which can only hold 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By doing this

```
fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 512, file)
```

you are asking `fread` to read 512 blocks, each block being `sizeof(buffer)` bytes long. I.e. you are trying to read 512*512 = 262144 bytes into an array declared as `uint8_t buffer[512]`. That certainly won't fit.

If you simply want to read data into the `buffer` array, that would be either

```
fread(buffer, sizeof buffer, 1, file)
```

or

```
fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, file)
```

or, if you prefer,

```
fread(buffer, sizeof *buffer, sizeof buffer / sizeof *buffer, file)
```

depending on what you consider an "atomic" data block in your read operation.

---

Also

```
sprintf(title, "%03d.jpg", currentImage);
```

will generate a string at least 7 characters long (e.g. `001.jpg`), which means that `title` has to be at least 8 characters long to accommodate zero terminator. However, your `title` is declared as

```
char title[7];
```

This is too small.

Comment: Hi AnT, thanks for pointing this error out. I have changed it to the fread(buffer, sizeof buffer, 1, file) but am still getting a segmentation fault unfortunately.

Comment: Hi AnT, I've included the new valgrind errors in my original post. Thanks

Comment: @edd91: Your code is incomplete, which makes it impossible to analyze it fully. However, as I added above, your `title` needs to be larger.

Comment: Hi @ant thanks for your help! It's fixed now, the title thing was throwing it after fixing the first issue.

How come I needed space for a \0 in title but not buffer? i.e. why shouldn't buffer be 513?

Comment: @edd91: Function `sprintf` builds a *string* in the target buffer. Which means that it writes the characters to the buffer and then caps them with a terminating `\0` character. That's how *strings* are built in C. A string of 7 characters long requires 8 characters to store it. Meanwhile, `fread` function does not work with strings and knows nothing about strings. It simply reads bytes from a file, as many as you ask it to read. It does not attempt to cap these bytes with any extra characters. You asked it to read 512 bytes - it read exactly 512 bytes. It does not do anything else.

Comment: Thanks @ant much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) of `fread()`, the signature is

> `size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE * stream );`

where the description is

> The function `fread()` reads `nmemb` elements of data, each `size` bytes long, from the stream pointed to by `stream`, storing them at the location given by `ptr`.

So, your code should be

```
 while (fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer[0]), 512, file) == 1)
```

Otherwise, you're ending up asking to read and store 512 number of blocks of size 512 bytes **each**, which is wrong and will cause buffer overflow, as reported by valgrind.